# Check that an Ito integral is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Before presenting my problem I will introduce some notation. Time index $t\in [0,T]$.

$$C_t =
\begin{cases}
Z_n = B_{t_{n-1}},  & \text{if $t=T$} \\[2ex]
Z_i = B_{t_{i-1}} , & \text{if $t_{i-1}\leq t\leq t_i$}
\end{cases}$$

where $C_t$ is a simple process and $B_t$ is brownian motion at time $t$.

The Ito integral of $C_t$ on $[0,t]$ with the partition defined by $t_{k-1}\leq t \leq t_k$, is given by
$$ I_t(C)=\int_0^t C_sdB_s :=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}Z_i(B_i-B_{i-1}) + Z_k(B_t-B_{t_{k-1}}).$$

In addition, $I_t(C)$ is a martingale with respect to the natural brownian filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t, \, t\in [0,T]).$

I am trying to check that $E[I_t(C)|\mathcal{F}_s]= I_s(C)$ when $s\in[t_{l-1},t_l]$ and $t\in[t_{k-1}, t_k]$ with $l<k$.
To do this, I want to use the following decomposition

$$I_t(C)=I_s(C)+R(s,t)$$

with

$$R(s,t)=Z_l(B_{t_l}-B_s)+\sum_{l+1}^{k-1}Z_i(B_i-B_{i-1})+Z_k(B_t-B_{t_{k-1}}).$$

So I need to show that $E[R(s,t)|\mathcal{F}_s]= 0$.

In my attempt I tackle each of the 3 terms of $R(s,t)$, one at a time.

First, since $Z_l$ is function of $B$ up to time s and $(B_{t_l}-B_s)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$:

$$E[Z_l(B_{t_l}-B_s)|\mathcal{F}_s]=Z_lE[(B_{t_l}-B_s)|\mathcal{F}_s]=Z_lE[(B_{t_l}-B_s)]=0.$$

Next, since
\begin{align}
E[Z_i(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})|\mathcal{F}_s] = E[B_{t_{i-1}}B_{t_i}|\mathcal{F}_s]-E[B_{t_{i-1}}^2|\mathcal{F}_s] &= E[B_{t_{i-1}}B_{t_i}]-(t_{i-1}-s+B_s^2)\\&=t_{i-1}-(t_{i-1}-s+B_s^2).
\end{align}
I find
$$E\left[\sum_{l+1}^{k-1}Z_i(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})\bigg|\mathcal{F}_s\right] = \sum_{l+1}^{k-1}E[B_{t_{i-1}}(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})|\mathcal{F}_s] = (s-B_s^2)\sum_{l+1}^{k-1}1 =  (s-B_s^2)(k-1-l).$$

And finally

$$E[Z_k(B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}})|\mathcal{F}_s]=(s-B_s^2).$$

Summing up every result I obtain 
$$0+(s-B_s^2)(k-l-1)+(s-B_s^2)=(s-B_s^2)(k-l).$$

And this is not zero.
So I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think your mistake might be in going from $\mathbb{E}\left\lbrack B_i B_{i-1} \middle| \mathcal{F}_s \right\rbrack$ to $\mathbb{E}\left\lbrack B_i B_{i-1} \right\rbrack$ in the line after "Next, since".

Comment: Why? What is $E[B_{t_i}B_{t_{i-1}}|\mathcal{F}_s]$ then? I know that $B_{t_i}$ and $B_{t_{i-1}}$ contain information that is not contained in $\mathcal{F}_s$ because $t_i, t_{i-1}\geq s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in rewriting $\mathbb{E}\left\lbrack B_{t_i} B_{t_{i-1}} \middle| \mathcal{F}_s\right\rbrack$ as $\mathbb{E}\left\lbrack B_{t_i} B_{t_{i-1}} \right\rbrack$.

In making that step in your working, you're implicitly assuming that $B_{t_i}B_{t_{i-1}}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$; this isn't the case for any time indices $t_i$ & $t_{i-1}$ - intuitively, knowing $(B_r, 0 \leq r \leq s)$ tells you something about the value of $B_{t_i} B_{t_{i-1}}$. There's an often-used trick to evaluate conditional expectations like this, which is to write

$B_{t_i}B_{t_{i-1}} = ((B_{t_i} - B_s) + B_s)((B_{t_{i-1}} - B_s) + B_s)$

and expand the outer brackets.