# Showing an Ito Integral is a Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm tasked with showing that the Ito integral with respect to a standard Wiener process

$$
\int^t_0 g(W_s,s)dW_s = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum^{n-1}_{k=0} f(W_{t_i},t_i)(W_{t_i + 1}-W_{t_i})
$$

where $f$ is a simple process, $t_i = \frac{it}{n}$, $0=t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_{n-1} < t_n = t$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ has an expectation of 0

$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int^t_0 g(W_s,s)dW_s\bigg]=0
$$

I assume that this should follow the same lines as [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667104/check-that-an-ito-integral-is-a-martingale); however, I am unsure how the 2 fit together. Is it that $C_s$ is directly equivalent to $g_s$ here?

Comment: Here's what i reckon you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what i reckon you want to do. Write $h(t) = \int_0^t g(W_s, s)dW_s $. Find $\mathbb{E}[h(t)-h(s) + h(s) | \mathscr{F}_s]$.

You can say that $\mathbb{E}[h(t)-h(s) | \mathscr{F}_s] =0$.

Why is it equal to $0$? It is nothing but the integral between $s$ and $t$, and it does not mind about the past. So you can turn it into an unconditional expectation and use the mean value property to say it is zero.

and $ \mathbb{E}[h(s) | \mathscr{F}_s] = h(s)$ as this is deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the response @GeorgeDewhirst . How does the filtration come into play on this though?

Comment: My answer shows that $h(s)$ is a martingale. If you want to show the mean value property of an Ito integral, that is a different question!

Comment: http://www.sta.cuhk.edu.hk/cyyau/course/2013f_rmsc4005/chapter6.pdf pg115